# Cannot connect to Wi-Fi after changing the SSID (Even after factory reset)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

Last week, I changed the name of our wireless network. The new name is broadcasting fine. Tried to connect to it from a few different devices, and I get a "Can't connect.." message on the computers, smartphones just try to connect for a few seconds and then nothing. I have tried forgetting the network, then reconnecting, still nothing. Changed the SSID back to what it was, still can't connect. I figured the wireless was shot in the router (Belkin DSL-2750B combo modem/router). Customer service sent me a new one. All was good at setup. Changed the SSID (kicking myself hard now) and same issue!

So I think the hardware is ruled out. I have changed the SSID multiple times in the past and never had this issue. **Even after factory reset**, I cannot connect to the default SSID now. Have tried standard password entry and WPS methods to connect. Have disabled security entirely with same results.

One strange (to me) thing I notice, is the router is broadcasting a lot of packets over the wireless interface, even though nothing is connected. Not sure if this is normal or not.

I am totally lost on what to try next. Shouldn't every setting change back to default after a factory reset? Anyways, I would be very grateful for any ideas from the community.

Thank you!

[image: System Monitor Page]

Comment: Can you provide some information about the clients your trying to connection, what mode you they used, what frequency the used, and what frequency your access point transmits at.  Your access point (wlan) is connected to your lan, so its normal, for bytes to be transmitted.

Comment: Hi Ramhound. The devices are all operating on wireless N, with the exception of one desktop that uses a wireless G adapter. The AP is set to transmit at 802.11 b,g,n by default.

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Comment: @DavidPostill Although the issue was resolved, I was not sure why it worked. I was hoping for additional advice on possible root causes. Would the comment section be more appropriate in that case? My apologies though, I did go ahead and post an answer based on the steps I took. Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue by changing the MAC addresses of both the Wireless interface (wl0) and the LAN bridge interfaces of the router. These settings were changed within the [System->Network Settings] configuration page, having followed the proper MAC addressing format (http://sqa.fyicenter.com/Online_Test_Tools/MAC_Address_Format_Validator.php).

Following attempts to re-connect to the wireless network were successful.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you don't have `DHCP` on (in `wl0`), it may be the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! On this Q&A site we value [answers](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) that are definitive, including steps to implement the solution and an explanation of how/why the answer solves the OPs question. Please consider expanding your answer accordingly.  Thanks for contributing.